# How to fix Kmymoney display size

Tags: 11.10, windows, kmymoney

I have loaded ubuntu 11.10 today but I am having problems with Kmymoney. The display size of the program is to big for my screen and I cannot resize it. It just does not seem to work due to this. I am running the same program in Windows and earlier versions in Ubuntu 10.04. These are all ok.

I am using a eee1000h 10" netbook. Any help would be appreciated. I am not a Linux expert so go easy with any answer.

The program is usable using the keyboard commands, but the GUI is 'broken' due to the program display size being too big for the screen. There is no apparent way to resize the display. This appears to be an issue introduced in 11.10.

Comment: Is the KmyMoney window in fullscreen mode? If so, the answer to this question may help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/13227/how-do-i-un-fullscreen-kmymoney

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem and solved it as follows:

Install `gnome-tweak-tool` with `apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`.

You can start the graphical program from the command prompt with `gnome-tweak-tool`. There is an Advanced Settings > Fonts section, that will allow you to change the font size.

Good Luck!